# How do I step into arbitrary generator function call from pdb console?

Tags: python, pdb

I have a generator function that misbehaves, which I would like to call from the pdb console and then step through each iteration of it to see which part of it is wrong. I was hoping I could

```
(Pdb) !pdb.runcall(broken_function, with_arg)
```

but it since the function is a generator all I got back was

```
<generator object broken_function at 0x2badc30>
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I can do at this point?

Edit: I should have made this clear earlier: I'd of course like to just set a breakpoint in the relevant loop, but I'm running the code off of a (for me) read-only file system, which makes that impractical.

Comment: I saw your edit and added an edit to my answer that makes the answer clear (instead of having it be in the middle of the example).  You don't need to set a breakpoint in the relevant loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily step into any generator and step through it, my answer is somewhat similar to [toes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798847/toes).

Let say we have a function

```
no = 4
def func(no):
    for i in range(0,no):
        yield i
```

To step into the function `func` and iterating through it, you can use `pdb.runcall` and an iterator `next`, so I have used both and created a function `debug_gen` and this function will help in debugging the generator.

```
def debug_gen(func,*args,**kwargs):
x = func(*args, **kwargs)
results = []
try:
    while True:
            result = pdb.runcall(next, x)
            results.append(result)
except StopIteration:
    return results
```

so you just have to pass the function to `debug_gen` with arguments and keyword arguments (if any) and after that, you have to call the `debug_gen` function anywhere to debug any generator function.

Comment: This seems by far like the cleanest solution. I don't have the problem anymore, but I'll accept yours as the answer unless someone has a strong objection. :)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Short version:

Options:

1. Target your function using `pdb.run('my_module.my_method()')` and step through the generator.
2. Call pdb as a script `python -m pdb my_script.py`.

Using test  file yippy_dog.py:

```
def yippy_dog():
    for i in range(10):
        print("YIP YIP!")

yippy_dog()
```

To target a generator from the pdb console, import your required modules and then call .run() on an invocation of the relevant method:

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import yippy_dog
YIP YIP!
~~~
YIP YIP!
YIP YIP!
>>> pdb.run('yippy_dog.yippy_dog()')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(1)yippy_dog()
-> def yippy_dog():
(Pdb) s
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(2)yippy_dog()
-> for i in range(10):
(Pdb) s
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(3)yippy_dog()
-> print("YIP YIP!")
(Pdb) s
YIP YIP!
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(2)yippy_dog()
-> for i in range(10):
(Pdb) s
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(3)yippy_dog()
-> print("YIP YIP!")
(Pdb) s
YIP YIP!
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(2)yippy_dog()
-> for i in range(10):
(Pdb) s
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(3)yippy_dog()
-> print("YIP YIP!")
(Pdb) s
YIP YIP!
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(2)yippy_dog()
-> for i in range(10):
(Pdb)
```

To run through a generator calling pdb as a script from the command line, invoke the pdb module and step to the relevant frame:

```
$ python -m pdb yippy_dog.py
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(1)<module>()
-> def yippy_dog():
(Pdb) step
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(5)<module>()
-> yippy_dog()
(Pdb) step
--Call--
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(1)yippy_dog()
-> def yippy_dog():
(Pdb) step
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(2)yippy_dog()
-> for i in range(10):
(Pdb) step
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(3)yippy_dog()
-> print("YIP YIP!")
(Pdb) step
YIP YIP!
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(2)yippy_dog()
-> for i in range(10):
(Pdb) step
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(3)yippy_dog()
-> print("YIP YIP!")
(Pdb) step
YIP YIP!
> /private/tmp/yippy_dog.py(2)yippy_dog()
-> for i in range(10):
```

You can, of course, manually force breakpoints by placing `set_trace()` inside your generator, but that requires modification/placing debugging in your target code, which may not be ideal.

Comment: This does not seem to work when `yippy_dog` is a generator function, since it returns immediately with the generator.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would try:

1. Set a break point in the body of the generator.
2. At the pdb prompt call a function which iterates through all of the values of the generator.

Example:

```
def mygen():
  for e in ...:
    ...               -- set a break point here, for instance
    yield ...

def testgen(g):       -- call this function from the pdb prompt
  for e in g: pass
```

You can also have `testgen()` directly call `mygen()` instead of requiring you to pass the generator in.

Comment: The problem is that I'm running the code from a read-only directory, so modifying the code is unfortunately not an option! I guess I should have specified that.

Comment: perhaps you can call `pdb.run("for e in mygen(): pass")` instead of defining `testgen()`.

Comment: You might be able to call `next(the_gen)` from pdb?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this. Seems to work, but maybe it's not what you are looking for:

```
# gen.py

def gen():
    while True:
        yield "foo"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = gen()
```

Then I fire up pdb:

```
$ python2.7 -m pdb gen.py 
> /home/elasand/prog/gen.py(1)<module>()
-> def gen():
(Pdb) s
> /home/elasand/prog/gen.py(5)<module>()
-> if __name__ == "__main__":
(Pdb) s
> /home/elasand/prog/gen.py(6)<module>()
-> g = gen()
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> /home/elasand/prog/gen.py(6)<module>()->None
-> g = gen()
(Pdb) !next(g)
'foo'
```

Comment: Not sure if this answer is what the OP wanted but this solved the problem for me. You can do this in ipython by importing the generator function, grabbing a generator (e.g.  `g= gen()`), and then calling ipdb.runcall on the `next` method (e.g. `ipdb.runcall(g.next)`).